# Angular search for date displayed as 'medium' but returned as yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ in JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, date

I am hoping that there is someone who can help me with filtering dates in ng-repeat.

On the website I am using a text field that searches the information returned from JSON and displays results that match the search.
However in the table I am showing the date as the medium format, so it displays for example "Apr 16, 2015 11:36:25 AM", but to find a result matching this date I would have to type "2015-04-16" in the text field, because the value for the date in JSON is "2015-04-16T10:36:25Z".

What I want to become is that the search works to display all results from for example April 16, when someone types "Apr 16" in the field as it shows "Apr 16" in the table.

I have this example for the data, it's a cut down example to only show what is important.

```
<tr id="usersData" ng-repeat="user in users.data | filter:usersSearchText">
<td>{{user.createdDate | date:'medium'}}</td>
</tr>
```

I know that the JSON object can be added in different date formats, but that's not an option for me.

In this example I have the Names and Created Date of the users, I want to use the search field to search for both Name and Created Date at the same time, but date in 'medium' format as it is displayed. Not in the way it is provided. http://plnkr.co/edit/Ssq4xeBHpNPrRgAbLVZs?p=preview

Does anyone have an idea what would be the best approach to get the result I am looking for? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a custom array filter...

```
.filter('SearchContains', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function (items, search) {
        if(typeof(search) == 'undefined') {return items;}
        var filtered = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            if ($filter('date')(item.createdDate, 'medium').indexOf(search) > -1 || item.name.indexOf(search) > -1) {
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    };
}])
```

with this:

```
<table id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th><th>Created Date</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="user in users | SearchContains:searchText">
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{user.createdDate | date:'medium'}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I just made a small example on Plunker. I want to be able to use the search for searching both the Name of a user and the Created Date on the way that it is written in the 'medium' format. http://plnkr.co/edit/Ssq4xeBHpNPrRgAbLVZs?p=preview

Comment: I have edited my answer and created http://plnkr.co/edit/CaAT1YPUeABD5UbPnvnG?p=preview . Not sure what you means by the "same time" though. But - I reckon a custom filter can be the way to go.